# How to create an animation from 2 Arraylists that store the values of x,y and the time change between integrer indexes is given?

Tags: java, animation, arraylist, simulation, physics

Im currently working on a **3-body-simulation (gravity)** and I managed to calculate every new x and y value by randomly guessing dt (the **time steps**) and putting them **into an iterative equation**. **I then saved each x and y value in an ArrayList after every iteration which covers the time dt that I put into a variable.** Im very very new at Java and I'd appreciate every answer although I'd be more thankful for a, in consideration of my noobie knowledge, easier answer. (Im a 16y.o. non english speaker, I apologize for any mistakes)
I already imported ArrayList, List and LinkedList and an example of my x and y List would be

```
List<Double> xlistobject1 = new ArrayList<Double>();
List<Double> ylistobject1 = new ArrayList<Double>();
```

And in the while-loop-iteration-process:

```
xlistobject1.add(xobject1); // where xobject1 and yobject1 are the x and y
ylistobject1.add(yobject1); // coordinates
```

I've already researched the best ways to **animate** this but nothing worked for me. I really cant wrap my head around *Canvas, JFrame* and so on because they require so much prior knowledge to this topic. As the time-span would already be defined by the n-count of iterations*dt, I imagine that you can't just draw a dot on every position in the lists and press play because **to create a relatively smooth animation, you'd have to take a timer into this** to setup a fixed animation length like 30 seconds would imply that you rescale the time onto this fixed length and end up with an information loss of the exact coordinates as my monitor can only display 1920x1080 pixels?

What I've got already:

I've copied the only Frame that worked on my Eclipse-Installation (at the bottom of the text) and removed the moving-part that was there already in an attempt of moving to the value of x and y that was in the in the lists looped until my lists are clear. After that I would rescale the time of the simulation (n-counter * dt) so that it would fit into 20 seconds with 30 frames per second so that the simulation had 600 timesteps and so if I didnt get something wrong, you'd have to divide (n-counter *dt)/600 to get the x- and y-scaling factors. My main problem is the implementation of my idea into Java. I hope I didn't confuse you or talked total bs. Thanks for any help! :)
Here's my "animation"-code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Vector;
import java.util.Stack;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

final public class Test
{

JFrame frame;
DrawPanel drawPanel;

private int oneX = 7;
private int oneY = 7;

public static void main(String... args)
{
    new Test().go();
}

private void go()
{
    frame = new JFrame("Test");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    drawPanel = new DrawPanel();

    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, drawPanel);

    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setSize(1920, 1000);
    frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    moveIt();
}

class DrawPanel extends JPanel
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillRect(3, 3, this.getWidth() - 6, this.getHeight() - 6);
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(6, 6, this.getWidth() - 12, this.getHeight() - 12);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(oneX, oneY, 6, 6);
        // Object 1
   !    for i = 0 to xlistobject1.count - 1
   !    //move circle to x=xlistobject1.item(i)
   !    //move circle to y=ylistobject1.item(i)
                next

                try
                { 
                     Thread.sleep(10);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
               {
                e.printStackTrace();
               }
               frame.repaint();
    }
}
```

}

##########################################################
I've made changes:
-instead of a List of coordinates, I now have a List of Point2d that stores coordinates

Code for the animation part:

```
    import java.awt.BorderLayout;
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Graphics;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import javax.swing.Timer;
    
   final public  class altanim {
    
        JFrame frame;DrawPanel drawPanel; public static int ni=1;  public static Boolean returnt=false;  public static Double plus1x, plus2x, plus3x, plus1y, plus2y, plus3y;
        public static Double zugriff1x=0.0, zugriff2x=0.0, zugriff3x=0.0, zugriff1y=0.0,zugriff2y=0.0, zugriff3y=0.0, nialtx3=0.0,nialtx2=0.0, nialtx1=0.0, nialty1=0.0, nialty2=0.0, nialty3=0.0;
        
            public static void main(String... args)  { 
            new altanim().go();
            }
            
            public void go()  {     
        if (returnt==false) {
        frame=new JFrame("3-Körper-Problem: Simulation:");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        drawPanel = new DrawPanel();
            frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, drawPanel);
            frame.setResizable(true);frame.setSize(3000,1600);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setGlassPane(drawPanel);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);    
                     returnt=true;}
    
                Timer timer = new Timer(10, new ActionListener() { 
                    @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (!(leololwjkr2.listepunkteobjekt1.size()==0) && ni<leololwjkr2.listepunkteobjekt1.size()-1) {
    System.out.println(ni+2+"...");       zugriff1x=leololwjkr2.listepunkteobjekt1.get(ni).getX();
    zugriff2x=leololwjkr2.listepunkteobjekt2.get(ni).getX();
    zugriff3x=leololwjkr2.listepunkteobjekt3.get(ni).getX();      zugriff1y=leololwjkr2.listepunkteobjekt1.get(ni).getY();
    zugriff2y=leololwjkr2.listepunkteobjekt2.get(ni).getY();
    zugriff3y=leololwjkr2.listepunkteobjekt3.get(ni).getY();
    ni++ ;
            plus1x=zugriff1x; 
    plus2x=zugriff2x; 
    plus3x=zugriff3x; 
    plus1y=zugriff1y; 
    plus2y=zugriff2y; 
    plus3y=zugriff3y;
        } 
else {System.out.println("Fertig"); 
try {Thread.sleep(3000);} catch (Exception e4) {System.out.println(e);}         drawPanel.repaint();    }  }   }); timer.start();   }
    
        
        class DrawPanel extends JPanel { private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L; 
        
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {        
            System.out.println("nächstes...");                        
            g.setColor(Color.BLUE);  g.fillRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());g.setColor(Color.RED);   g.fillRect(3, 3, this.getWidth() - 6, this.getHeight() - 6);g.setColor(Color.WHITE); g.fillRect(6, 6, this.getWidth() - 12, this.getHeight() - 12);           // Rahmen
                     g.setColor(Color.BLUE);g.drawLine(zugriff1x.intValue(), zugriff1y.intValue(), plus1x.intValue(), plus1y.intValue());
                     g.setColor(Color.RED);g.drawLine(zugriff2x.intValue(), zugriff2y.intValue(), plus2x.intValue(), plus2y.intValue());
                     g.setColor(Color.GREEN);g.drawLine(zugriff3x.intValue(), zugriff3y.intValue(), plus3x.intValue(), plus3y.intValue()); } 
        } 
    }
```

###############
My problem is that the paintComponent at the bottom doesn't do anything and I can't think of a solution. Please take a look at it. :)

Answer (score 0):

The important thing to understand is the `paintComponent` method just draws the component as it appears at that moment in time -- it is not a place to do animation.

I have made two minor changes to your code to give you this idea:

1. Removed the loop and the sleep from `paintComponent`.
2. Added a timer which modifies `oneX` and `oneY` and triggers a repaint of your `DrawPanel`.

You will want to do more complicated updating of x and y coordinates, and you'll want to draw more things in `paintComponent`, but I hope this will get you started.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

final public class SwingTest
{

    JFrame frame;
    DrawPanel drawPanel;

    private int oneX = 7;
    private int oneY = 7;

    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        new SwingTest().go();
    }

    private void go()
    {
        frame = new JFrame("Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        drawPanel = new DrawPanel();

        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, drawPanel);

        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setSize(1920, 1000);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        // added this timer, which updates every 100ms
        Timer timer = new Timer(100, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // move the box
                oneX += 1;
                oneY += 1;
                drawPanel.repaint();
            }
        });
        timer.start();
    }

    class DrawPanel extends JPanel
    {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
        {
            g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.fillRect(3, 3, this.getWidth() - 6, this.getHeight() - 6);
            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g.fillRect(6, 6, this.getWidth() - 12, this.getHeight() - 12);
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.fillRect(oneX, oneY, 6, 6);
            // removed your loop
        }
    }
}
```

Another tip to think about in the future: Create a class for each object you want to display, and have a list of instances of this class, instead of a separate list for each attribute of the object. That way there's just one insert operation when you create a new objects, and a single `get` from the list gives you all the attributes you need to draw or update it.

Comment: Hi. I've now got a List of Point2D that store the Coordinates. My new Code has one tiny error which stops the paintComponent from Updating or even draw anything in the first place. Could you take a look at it?

Comment: @LeoAcc when you say it "doesn't do anything", do you mean that it doesn't get called, or that you don't see anything drawn?

Comment: It doesn't draw anything. When I go look at it in debugger mode, I see that it (paintComponent) doesn't even get called although reaching the repaint().

Comment: Why are you using drawPanel as a glassPane? Glasspanes are hidden when they are added. You will either need to remove the call to `setGlassPane` or add             `drawPanel.setVisible(true)` after you have called it.